# SQL to return number of years since last purchase of an item

Tags: sql

I have a table of purchases with the following properties:

- id
- user_id (foreign key)
- date
- value

I'm trying to come up with a SQL query that returns the: number of total purchases of a user, the total value of everything and how many years have passed since last purchase. Something like:

```
| total purchases | years | total amount spent
| 10              | 2     | 500.0
```

I have never been good with SQL and a little help is appreciated. I'm stuck at:

```
  SELECT
    ? as 'total purchases',
    ? as 'years',
    ? as 'total amount spent'
  FROM purchases
  ?
```

Comment: Please show us what your `purchases` table looks like with some example data. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Additionally https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count will get you 2 of your columns, and probably https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_max will help you with the years, but you'll need to calculate that from today's date. Additionally, please tag your question with your SQL version.

Comment: Assuming that your SQL version has function `YEAR` that returns year as number, `YEAR(NOW() - YEAR(MAX(date)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @PM77-1 careful with that; if it's Jan 1st and I just bought an Xbox on Dec 31st, it's been a year since I bought an Xbox

Comment: @CaiusJard - I was not suggesting a formula. I was showing an approach that you apply a function to a result of aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

As the actual DB is not tagged, I have tried with Oracle (would not be much different with other databases) and find the approach below,

```
SELECT userid,
    count(*) as "total purchases",
    (extract (year from sysdate) - extract (year from max(purchase_date))) as "last purchase since(year)",
    sum(value) as "total amount spent"
  FROM purchases
GROUP BY userid
```

<kbd>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c70a6477d0fab74569a26139bc81d8e0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Select the ID, the sum of the values and use DATEDIFF to calculate the years since last purchase.
[w3schools - DATEDIFF()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

```
SELECT
user_id, COUNT(user_id) as 'num_purchases', SUM(value) as 'Total', 
DATEDIFF(year, DATE(NOW()), MAX(date))
FROM
purchases
GROUP BY 1;
```